# how to find nearest marker from user location and showing one

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, marker

How do find nearest marker  to user location ?

I have 10 marker, and in the and showing the nearest  marker in map with route.

this my MapDirection.class

```
public class MapDirection extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;
Button btnShowNearestMarker;
Button btnShowDistance;
Button btnShowMarker;

GPSLocationService gpsLocationService;
MarkerVShelter markerVShelter;

private LatLng Mark_Kantor_Gubernur = new LatLng(-0.9376155, 100.3600001);
private LatLng Mark_Bappeda_prov_Sumbar = new LatLng(-0.913884, 100.359176);
private LatLng Mark_Mesjid_Muhajirin = new LatLng(-0.8908614, 100.3538605);
private LatLng Mark_Gedung_Pasar_Raya = new LatLng(-0.9497613, 100.3606601);
private LatLng Mark_SMA_N_1_Pdg = new LatLng(-0.9476911, 100.3625053);
private LatLng Mark_SMK_N_5_Pdg = new LatLng(-0.92146, 100.3518);
private LatLng Mark_SMP_N_7_Pdg = new LatLng(-0.92073, 100.351575);
private LatLng Mark_SMP_N_25_Pdg = new LatLng(-0.920035, 100.3561025);
private LatLng Mark_SD_N_15_Lolong = new LatLng(-0.94086, 100.36316);
private LatLng Mark_SD_N_23_U_Gurun = new LatLng(-0.93373, 100.35444);

private Polyline newPolyline;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_direction_layout);

    //Getting Map From Google
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

    //Set Attribute in first Opening
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

    gpsLocationService = new GPSLocationService(MapDirection.this);
    Location gpsLocation = gpsLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (gpsLocation != null) {
        double latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobile Location (GPS) : \nLatitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Handle map in firts opening
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

        // Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 5000, null);

        // Construct a CameraPosition focusing on Mountain View and animate the camera to that position.
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng)             // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(180)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }
    else
    {
        showGPSAlertDialog();
    }

    //Setting UP ALL Marker
    //Shelter
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_Kantor_Gubernur)
            .title("Kantor Gubernur")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_Bappeda_prov_Sumbar)
            .title("Kantor Bappeda Prov. SUMBAR")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_Mesjid_Muhajirin)
            .title("Mesjid Muhajirin")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_Gedung_Pasar_Raya)
            .title("Gedung Pasar Raya")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_SMA_N_1_Pdg)
            .title("Gedung SMA N 1 Padang")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_SMK_N_5_Pdg)
            .title("Gedung SMK N 5 Padang")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_SMP_N_7_Pdg)
            .title("Gedung SMP N 7 Padang")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_SMP_N_25_Pdg)
            .title("Gedung SMP N 25 Padang")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_SD_N_15_Lolong)
            .title("Gedung SD N 15 Lolong")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Mark_SD_N_23_U_Gurun)
            .title("Gedung SD N 25, Ujung Gurun, Padang")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));

    //Setting onclick marker & Direction to Marker
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);



}

public void showGPSAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapDirection.this);

    //Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Setting");

    //setting dialog message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Your GPS is Offline");

    //setting button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    //on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}


@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    findDirections(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude(), marker.getPosition().latitude,
            marker.getPosition().longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);

    return false;
}

public void findDirections(double fromPositionDoubleLat, double fromPositionDoubleLong, double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(GetDirectionAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LAT, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LONG, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);

    GetDirectionAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetDirectionAsyncTask(this);
    asyncTask.execute(map);
}

public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints) {
    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.BLUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < directionPoints.size(); i++) {
        rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
    }
    if (newPolyline != null) {
        newPolyline.remove();
    }
    newPolyline = googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
}
```

}

to find route user location to marker i use this [Tutorial](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

Answer (score 0):

for each marker plot a route to marker from your current location . you will get a distance to the marker. Store the same in an array . Do the same activity for the rest of the marker. Finally you will be able to tell which marker is the nearest and plot its route on the map.

Following formula can be used instead to calculate distance between 2 co-ordinates

```
int R = 6371; // km
double x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
double y = (lat2 - lat1);
double distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R;
```